# Install Ubuntu without creating a user account

Tags: installation, users

I'd like to sell an old computer of mine to a friend, and I'd like to pre-install Ubuntu. Is it possible to install the OS, but not set up a user account first? I'm expecting that it would ask the user to set up the account (and choose a language, keyboard layout, timezone, etc.) when the computer is booted up for the first time. Basically, the type of prompt you would receive when you first boot up a new Mac or Windows machine.

Is there any way to do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Boot your installation disk (I recommend 12.04 LTS, because it will be supported until 2017). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to the boot menu.
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> and select *OEM Install*.
3. Install. It will ask for a temporary user name and password.
4. Boot into the system. Tailor to your heart's content.
5. Once working, open *Prepare for shipping to end user*.
6. Do **not** boot into the system again.

You may want to clone an image of the drive as a backup (try [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [RedoBackup](http://redobackup.org/)).

Comment: 3 questions:

0. Is it still possible with ubuntu 18.04?
1. What can I do at point 4?
2. At point 5, will the image ship all the drivers?

Comment: @valeriocomo Point 4, practically anything. You can reboot as necessary. Point 5, there's nothing to ship; the computer is ready. I haven't tried 18.04, sorry.